# Condición de carrera problema productor consumidor

Tags: c++, hilos

Estoy mirando el problema del productor consumidor típico de threads en c++11. Mirando implementaciones de las distintas soluciones al problema me tope con esta:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <thread>
#include <mutex>
#include <atomic>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>
using namespace std;

// print function for "thread safe" printing using a stringstream
 void print(ostream& s) { cout << s.rdbuf(); cout.flush(); s.clear(); }

const int num_producers = 5;
const int num_consumers = 10;
const int producer_delay_to_produce = 10;   
const int consumer_delay_to_consume = 30;  
const int consumer_max_wait_time = 200;     
const int max_production = 10;              
const int max_products = 10;                

atomic<int> num_producers_working(0);       
stack<int> products;                        
mutex xmutex;
mutex nuevo_mutx;                         

condition_variable is_not_full;             
condition_variable is_not_empty;            

void produce(int producer_id)
{
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(xmutex);
        int product;

        is_not_full.wait(lock, [] { return products.size() != max_products; });
        product = products.size();
        products.push(product);

         print(stringstream() << "Producer " << producer_id << " produced " << product << "\n");
       is_not_empty.notify_all();
}

void consume(int consumer_id)
{
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(xmutex);
        int product;

        if(is_not_empty.wait_for(lock, chrono::milliseconds(consumer_max_wait_time),
                [] { return products.size() > 0; }))
        {
                product = products.top();
                products.pop();

                 print(stringstream() << "Consumer " << consumer_id << " consumed " << product << "\n");
                is_not_full.notify_all();
        }
}
void producer(int id)
{
        ++num_producers_working;
        for(int i = 0; i < max_production; ++i)
        {

                produce(id);
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(producer_delay_to_produce));
        }

         print(stringstream() << "Producer " << id << " has exited\n");
         --num_producers_working;
}

void consumer(int id)
{
        // Wait until there is any producer working

        while(num_producers_working == 0) this_thread::yield();
        unique_lock<mutex> lock(nuevo_mutx);
        while(num_producers_working != 0 || products.size() > 0)
        {
                consume(id);
                this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(consumer_delay_to_consume));
        }

         print(stringstream() << "Consumer " << id << " has exited\n");
 }
int main()
{
        vector<thread> producers_and_consumers;

        // Create producers
        for(int i = 0; i < num_producers; ++i)
                producers_and_consumers.push_back(thread(producer, i));

        // Create consumers
        for(int i = 0; i < num_consumers; ++i)
                producers_and_consumers.push_back(thread(consumer, i));

        // Wait for consumers and producers to finish
        for(auto& t : producers_and_consumers)
                t.join();
}
```

Al ejecutar el código con helgrind de valgrind da una condición de carrera, mirando el log que nos deja helgrind creo que los tiros pueden venir por la función consumer, pero no doy encontrado el problema y su solución.
El log que da helgrind:

```
==7004== Helgrind, a thread error detector
==7004== Copyright (C) 2007-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by OpenWorks LLP et al.
==7004== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==7004== Command: ./a.out
==7004== Producer 0 produced 0 Producer 1 produced 1 Producer 2 produced 2 Producer 3 produced 3 Producer 4 produced 4 Consumer 0 consumed 4 Producer 2 produced 4 Producer 1 produced 5 Producer 0 produced 6 Producer 3 produced 7 Producer 4 produced 8 Consumer 1 consumed 8 Consumer 2 consumed 7 Consumer 3 consumed 6 Producer 1 produced 6 Producer 2 produced 7 Producer 4 produced 8 Producer 3 produced 9 Consumer 4 consumed 9 Producer 0 produced 9 Consumer 5 consumed 9 Producer 1 produced 9 Consumer 6 consumed 9 Producer 2 produced 9 Consumer 7 consumed 9 Producer 4 produced 9 Consumer 8 consumed 9 Consumer 0 consumed 8 Producer 1 produced 8 Producer 3 produced 9 Consumer 1 consumed 9 Producer 0 produced 9 Consumer 2 consumed 9 Producer 2 produced 9 Consumer 9 consumed 9 Consumer 3 consumed 8 Producer 4 produced 8 Producer 1 produced 9 Consumer 4 consumed 9 Producer 3 produced 9 Consumer 5 consumed 9 Producer 4 produced 9 Consumer 6 consumed 9 Producer 2 produced 9 Consumer 7 consumed 9 Producer 0 produced 9 Consumer 0 consumed 9 Producer 4 produced 9 Consumer 8 consumed 9 Producer 3 produced 9 Consumer 1 consumed 9 Producer 1 produced 9 Consumer 2 consumed 9 Producer 2 produced 9 Consumer 3 consumed 9 Producer 0 produced 9 Consumer 9 consumed 9 Producer 4 produced 9 Consumer 4 consumed 9 Producer 3 produced 9 Consumer 5 consumed 9 Producer 0 produced 9 Consumer 6 consumed 9 Producer 1 produced 9 Consumer 7 consumed 9 Producer 3 produced 9 Consumer 0 consumed 9 Consumer 8 consumed 8 Producer 2 produced 8 Producer 4 produced 9 Consumer 1 consumed 9 Consumer 2 consumed 8 Producer 0 produced 8 Producer 1 produced 9 Consumer 3 consumed 9 Producer 3 produced 9 Consumer 9 consumed 9 Producer 2 produced 9 Consumer 4 consumed 9 Producer 1 produced 9 Consumer 5 consumed 9 Producer 0 produced 9 Consumer 6 consumed 9 Producer 4 produced 9 Consumer 7 consumed 9 Producer 2 produced 9
==7004== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==7004==
==7004== Thread #3 was created
==7004==    at 0x572387E: clone (clone.S:71)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: create_thread (createthread.c:100)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:797)
==7004==    by 0x4C36A27: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x4EFF834: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x10AEB0: std::thread::thread<void (&)(int), int&>(void (&)(int), int&) (thread:126)
==7004==    by 0x109EF1: main (nuevo.cpp:93)
==7004==
==7004== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==7004==
==7004== Thread #4 was created
==7004==    at 0x572387E: clone (clone.S:71)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: create_thread (createthread.c:100)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:797)
==7004==    by 0x4C36A27: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x4EFF834: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x10AEB0: std::thread::thread<void (&)(int), int&>(void (&)(int), int&) (thread:126)
==7004==    by 0x109EF1: main (nuevo.cpp:93)
==7004==
==7004== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==7004==
==7004== Thread #2 was created
==7004==    at 0x572387E: clone (clone.S:71)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: create_thread (createthread.c:100)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:797)
==7004==    by 0x4C36A27: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x4EFF834: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x10AEB0: std::thread::thread<void (&)(int), int&>(void (&)(int), int&) (thread:126)
==7004==    by 0x109EF1: main (nuevo.cpp:93)
==7004==
==7004== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==7004==
==7004==  Lock at 0x3121C0 was first observed
==7004==    at 0x4C3403C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x1097F9: __gthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t*) (gthr-default.h:748)
==7004==    by 0x10A613: std::mutex::lock() (std_mutex.h:103)
==7004==    by 0x10B138: std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock() (std_mutex.h:267)
==7004==    by 0x10A751: std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock(std::mutex&) (std_mutex.h:197)
==7004==    by 0x109925: produce(int) (nuevo.cpp:33)
==7004==    by 0x109C6D: producer(int) (nuevo.cpp:65)
==7004==    by 0x10B73E: void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(int), int>(std::__invoke_other, void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:60)
==7004==    by 0x10ADF9: std::__invoke_result<void (*)(int), int>::type std::__invoke<void (*)(int), int>(void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:95)
==7004==    by 0x10DCC2: decltype (__invoke((_S_declval<0ul>)(), (_S_declval<1ul>)())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>) (thread:234)
==7004==    by 0x10DC63: std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::operator()() (thread:243)
==7004==    by 0x10DC33: std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> > >::_M_run() (thread:186)
==7004==  Address 0x3121c0 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "xmutex"
==7004==
==7004== Possible data race during write of size 1 at 0x5DA3350 by thread #3
==7004== Locks held: none
==7004==    at 0x4C3C56C: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x568D993: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1258)
==7004==    by 0x5681976: fwrite (iofwrite.c:39)
==7004==    by 0x4EEE3B4: long std::__copy_streambufs_eof<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, bool&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x4F55827: std::ostream::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x109899: print(std::ostream&) (nuevo.cpp:13)
==7004==    by 0x109CFD: producer(int) (nuevo.cpp:69)
==7004==    by 0x10B73E: void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(int), int>(std::__invoke_other, void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:60)
==7004==    by 0x10ADF9: std::__invoke_result<void (*)(int), int>::type std::__invoke<void (*)(int), int>(void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:95)
==7004==    by 0x10DCC2: decltype (__invoke((_S_declval<0ul>)(), (_S_declval<1ul>)())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>) (thread:234)
==7004==    by 0x10DC63: std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::operator()() (thread:243)
==7004==    by 0x10DC33: std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> > >::_M_run() (thread:186)
==7004==
==7004== This conflicts with a previous write of size 1 by thread #4
==7004== Locks held: 1, at address 0x3121C0
==7004==    at 0x4C3C546: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x568D993: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1258)
==7004==    by 0x5681976: fwrite (iofwrite.c:39)
==7004==    by 0x4EEE3B4: long std::__copy_streambufs_eof<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, bool&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x4F55827: std::ostream::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x109899: print(std::ostream&) (nuevo.cpp:13)
==7004==    by 0x1099F0: produce(int) (nuevo.cpp:40)
==7004==    by 0x109C6D: producer(int) (nuevo.cpp:65)
==7004==  Address 0x5da3350 is 0 bytes inside a block of size 1,024 alloc'd
==7004==    at 0x4C30F2F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x568018B: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==7004==    by 0x5690378: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:365)
==7004==    by 0x568F497: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:759)
==7004==    by 0x568D9EC: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1266)
==7004==    by 0x5681976: fwrite (iofwrite.c:39)
==7004==    by 0x4EEE3B4: long std::__copy_streambufs_eof<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, bool&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x4F55827: std::ostream::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x109899: print(std::ostream&) (nuevo.cpp:13)
==7004==    by 0x1099F0: produce(int) (nuevo.cpp:40)
==7004==    by 0x109C6D: producer(int) (nuevo.cpp:65)
==7004==    by 0x10B73E: void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(int), int>(std::__invoke_other, void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:60)
==7004==  Block was alloc'd by thread #2
==7004== Producer 1 has eConsumer 2 consumed 9
==7004== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==7004==
==7004== Thread #15 was created
==7004==    at 0x572387E: clone (clone.S:71)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: create_thread (createthread.c:100)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:797)
==7004==    by 0x4C36A27: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x4EFF834: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x10AEB0: std::thread::thread<void (&)(int), int&>(void (&)(int), int&) (thread:126)
==7004==    by 0x109F41: main (nuevo.cpp:97)
==7004==
==7004== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==7004==
==7004== Thread #9 was created
==7004==    at 0x572387E: clone (clone.S:71)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: create_thread (createthread.c:100)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:797)
==7004==    by 0x4C36A27: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x4EFF834: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x10AEB0: std::thread::thread<void (&)(int), int&>(void (&)(int), int&) (thread:126)
==7004==    by 0x109F41: main (nuevo.cpp:97)
==7004==
==7004== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==7004==
==7004==  Lock at 0x3121C0 was first observed
==7004==    at 0x4C3403C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x1097F9: __gthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t*) (gthr-default.h:748)
==7004==    by 0x10A613: std::mutex::lock() (std_mutex.h:103)
==7004==    by 0x10B138: std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock() (std_mutex.h:267)
==7004==    by 0x10A751: std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock(std::mutex&) (std_mutex.h:197)
==7004==    by 0x109925: produce(int) (nuevo.cpp:33)
==7004==    by 0x109C6D: producer(int) (nuevo.cpp:65)
==7004==    by 0x10B73E: void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(int), int>(std::__invoke_other, void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:60)
==7004==    by 0x10ADF9: std::__invoke_result<void (*)(int), int>::type std::__invoke<void (*)(int), int>(void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:95)
==7004==    by 0x10DCC2: decltype (__invoke((_S_declval<0ul>)(), (_S_declval<1ul>)())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>) (thread:234)
==7004==    by 0x10DC63: std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::operator()() (thread:243)
==7004==    by 0x10DC33: std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> > >::_M_run() (thread:186)
==7004==  Address 0x3121c0 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "xmutex"
==7004==
==7004== Possible data race during write of size 1 at 0x5DA335F by thread #15
==7004== Locks held: 1, at address 0x3121C0
==7004==    at 0x4C3C546: mempcpy (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x568D993: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1258)
==7004==    by 0x5681976: fwrite (iofwrite.c:39)
==7004==    by 0x4EEE3B4: long std::__copy_streambufs_eof<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, bool&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x4F55827: std::ostream::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x109899: print(std::ostream&) (nuevo.cpp:13)
==7004==    by 0x109BA8: consume(int) (nuevo.cpp:55)
==7004==    by 0x109DD1: consumer(int) (nuevo.cpp:81)
==7004==    by 0x10B73E: void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(int), int>(std::__invoke_other, void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:60)
==7004==    by 0x10ADF9: std::__invoke_result<void (*)(int), int>::type std::__invoke<void (*)(int), int>(void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:95)
==7004==    by 0x10DCC2: decltype (__invoke((_S_declval<0ul>)(), (_S_declval<1ul>)())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>) (thread:234)
==7004==    by 0x10DC63: std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::operator()() (thread:243)
==7004==
==7004== This conflicts with a previous read of size 1 by thread #9
==7004== Locks held: 1, at address 0x3121C0
==7004==    at 0x5712187: write (write.c:27)
==7004==    by 0x568D1BC: _IO_file_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1203)
==7004==    by 0x568EF50: new_do_write (fileops.c:457)
==7004==    by 0x568EF50: _IO_do_write@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:433)
==7004==    by 0x568D9EC: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1266)
==7004==    by 0x5681976: fwrite (iofwrite.c:39)
==7004==    by 0x4EEE3B4: long std::__copy_streambufs_eof<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, bool&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x4F55827: std::ostream::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x109899: print(std::ostream&) (nuevo.cpp:13)
==7004==  Address 0x5da335f is 15 bytes inside a block of size 1,024 alloc'd
==7004==    at 0x4C30F2F: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x568018B: _IO_file_doallocate (filedoalloc.c:101)
==7004==    by 0x5690378: _IO_doallocbuf (genops.c:365)
==7004==    by 0x568F497: _IO_file_overflow@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:759)
==7004==    by 0x568D9EC: _IO_file_xsputn@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (fileops.c:1266)
==7004==    by 0x5681976: fwrite (iofwrite.c:39)
==7004==    by 0x4EEE3B4: long std::__copy_streambufs_eof<char, std::char_traits<char> >(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*, bool&) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x4F55827: std::ostream::operator<<(std::basic_streambuf<char, std::char_traits<char> >*) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x109899: print(std::ostream&) (nuevo.cpp:13)
==7004==    by 0x1099F0: produce(int) (nuevo.cpp:40)
==7004==    by 0x109C6D: producer(int) (nuevo.cpp:65)
==7004==    by 0x10B73E: void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(int), int>(std::__invoke_other, void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:60)
==7004==  Block was alloc'd by thread #2
==7004== Consumer 8 consumed 8 Consumer 1 consumed 7 Consumer 0 consumed 6 Producer 0 produced 6 Consumer 3 consumed 6 Producer 2 has exited Producer 4 has exited Consumer 9 consumed 5 xited Producer 3 produced 5 Consumer 4 consumed 5 Producer 0 has exited Consumer 5 consumed 4 Producer 3 has exited
==7004== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==7004==
==7004== Thread #13 was created
==7004==    at 0x572387E: clone (clone.S:71)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: create_thread (createthread.c:100)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:797)
==7004==    by 0x4C36A27: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x4EFF834: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x10AEB0: std::thread::thread<void (&)(int), int&>(void (&)(int), int&) (thread:126)
==7004==    by 0x109F41: main (nuevo.cpp:97)
==7004==
==7004== ---Thread-Announcement------------------------------------------
==7004==
==7004== Thread #12 was created
==7004==    at 0x572387E: clone (clone.S:71)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: create_thread (createthread.c:100)
==7004==    by 0x53EAEC4: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:797)
==7004==    by 0x4C36A27: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x4EFF834: std::thread::_M_start_thread(std::unique_ptr<std::thread::_State, std::default_delete<std::thread::_State> >, void (*)()) (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x10AEB0: std::thread::thread<void (&)(int), int&>(void (&)(int), int&) (thread:126)
==7004==    by 0x109F41: main (nuevo.cpp:97)
==7004==
==7004== ----------------------------------------------------------------
==7004==
==7004==  Lock at 0x3121C0 was first observed
==7004==    at 0x4C3403C: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x1097F9: __gthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t*) (gthr-default.h:748)
==7004==    by 0x10A613: std::mutex::lock() (std_mutex.h:103)
==7004==    by 0x10B138: std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::lock() (std_mutex.h:267)
==7004==    by 0x10A751: std::unique_lock<std::mutex>::unique_lock(std::mutex&) (std_mutex.h:197)
==7004==    by 0x109925: produce(int) (nuevo.cpp:33)
==7004==    by 0x109C6D: producer(int) (nuevo.cpp:65)
==7004==    by 0x10B73E: void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(int), int>(std::__invoke_other, void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:60)
==7004==    by 0x10ADF9: std::__invoke_result<void (*)(int), int>::type std::__invoke<void (*)(int), int>(void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:95)
==7004==    by 0x10DCC2: decltype (__invoke((_S_declval<0ul>)(), (_S_declval<1ul>)())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>) (thread:234)
==7004==    by 0x10DC63: std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::operator()() (thread:243)
==7004==    by 0x10DC33: std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> > >::_M_run() (thread:186)
==7004==  Address 0x3121c0 is 0 bytes inside data symbol "xmutex"
==7004==
==7004== Possible data race during read of size 8 at 0x312190 by thread #13
==7004== Locks held: none
==7004==    at 0x10BAE1: std::_Deque_iterator<int, int&, int*>::difference_type std::operator-<int, int&, int*>(std::_Deque_iterator<int, int&, int*> const&, std::_Deque_iterator<int, int&, int*> const&) (stl_deque.h:356)
==7004==    by 0x10B1B6: std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::size() const (stl_deque.h:1272)
==7004==    by 0x10A79D: std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >::size() const (stl_stack.h:191)
==7004==    by 0x109DAF: consumer(int) (nuevo.cpp:79)
==7004==    by 0x10B73E: void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(int), int>(std::__invoke_other, void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:60)
==7004==    by 0x10ADF9: std::__invoke_result<void (*)(int), int>::type std::__invoke<void (*)(int), int>(void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:95)
==7004==    by 0x10DCC2: decltype (__invoke((_S_declval<0ul>)(), (_S_declval<1ul>)())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>) (thread:234)
==7004==    by 0x10DC63: std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::operator()() (thread:243)
==7004==    by 0x10DC33: std::thread::_State_impl<std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> > >::_M_run() (thread:186)
==7004==    by 0x4EFF57E: ??? (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25)
==7004==    by 0x4C36C26: ??? (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_helgrind-amd64-linux.so)
==7004==    by 0x53EA6DA: start_thread (pthread_create.c:463)
==7004==
==7004== This conflicts with a previous write of size 8 by thread #12
==7004== Locks held: 1, at address 0x3121C0
==7004==    at 0x10B419: std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> >::pop_back() (stl_deque.h:1607)
==7004==    by 0x10A82D: std::stack<int, std::deque<int, std::allocator<int> > >::pop() (stl_stack.h:261)
==7004==    by 0x109B24: consume(int) (nuevo.cpp:53)
==7004==    by 0x109DD1: consumer(int) (nuevo.cpp:81)
==7004==    by 0x10B73E: void std::__invoke_impl<void, void (*)(int), int>(std::__invoke_other, void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:60)
==7004==    by 0x10ADF9: std::__invoke_result<void (*)(int), int>::type std::__invoke<void (*)(int), int>(void (*&&)(int), int&&) (invoke.h:95)
==7004==    by 0x10DCC2: decltype (__invoke((_S_declval<0ul>)(), (_S_declval<1ul>)())) std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::_M_invoke<0ul, 1ul>(std::_Index_tuple<0ul, 1ul>) (thread:234)
==7004==    by 0x10DC63: std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(int), int> >::operator()() (thread:243)
==7004==  Address 0x312190 is 48 bytes inside data symbol "products"
==7004== Consumer 6 consumed 3 Consumer 7 consumed 2 Consumer 2 consumed 1 Consumer 1 consumed 0 Consumer 0 has exited Consumer 3 has exited Consumer 8 has exited Consumer 9 has exited Consumer 4 has exited Consumer 5 has exited Consumer 7 has exited Consumer 6 has exited Consumer 2 has exited Consumer 1 has exited
==7004==
==7004== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==7004== Use --history-level=approx or =none to gain increased speed, at
==7004== the cost of reduced accuracy of conflicting-access information
==7004== ERROR SUMMARY: 599 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 1951 from 58)
```

Answer (score 2):

El código tiene un problema y es que estás lanzando la notificación cuando el bloqueo está aún activo:

```
void produce(int producer_id)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(xmutex);
    int product;

    is_not_full.wait(lock, [] { return products.size() != max_products; });
    product = products.size();
    products.push(product);

    print(stringstream() << "Producer " << producer_id << " produced " << product << "\n");
    is_not_empty.notify_all(); // <<--- AQUI
}

void consume(int consumer_id)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(xmutex);
    int product;

    if(is_not_empty.wait_for(lock, chrono::milliseconds(consumer_max_wait_time),
            [] { return products.size() > 0; }))
    {
        product = products.top();
        products.pop();

        print(stringstream() << "Consumer " << consumer_id << " consumed " << product << "\n");
        is_not_full.notify_all(); // <<--- AQUI
    }
}
```

Hay que liberar el bloqueo antes de lanzar la notificación. Si no corres el riesgo de que los hilos se despierten únicamente para acabar bloqueados otra vez:

```
void consume(int consumer_id)
{
    unique_lock<mutex> lock(xmutex);
    int product;

    if(is_not_empty.wait_for(lock, chrono::milliseconds(consumer_max_wait_time),
            [] { return products.size() > 0; }))
    {
        product = products.top();
        products.pop();

        print(stringstream() << "Consumer " << consumer_id << " consumed " << product << "\n");
        lock.unlock(); // <<--- Importante!!!
        is_not_full.notify_all();
    }
}
```

Comment: no me ha funcionado, helgrind me sigue advirtiendo de una condicion de carrera

Comment: Creo que es el método size de la función consumer

Answer (score 1):

He solucionado el problema de la condición de carrera, helgrind ya no se queja, la culpa la tenía el método size en la línea **while(num_producers_working != 0 || products.size() > 0)**
la solución más simple pasa por meter a size dentro de una sección crítica:
Código:

```
size_t stack_size(const stack<int> &obj ){
    lock_guard<mutex> guardian(xmutex);
    return obj.size();

}
```

Reemplazando la anterior: **while(num_producers_working != 0 || stack_size(products) > 0)**